# Filter tasks by age

Tags: camunda

Normal I'm looking for tasks as follows:

```
@Inject
TaskService taskService;

taskService.createTaskQuery()
                    .processDefinitionKey(ProcessVars.PROCESSKEY)
                    .taskCandidateGroupIn(list).initializeFormKeys().list();
```

How do I filter by age? Tasks older than 3 weeks as example. By HistoryService?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the TaskQuery [`taskCreatedBefore`](https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.4/org/camunda/bpm/engine/task/TaskQuery.html#taskCreatedBefore(java.util.Date)) or [`taskCreatedBeforeExpression`](https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.4/org/camunda/bpm/engine/task/TaskQuery.html#taskCreatedBeforeExpression(java.lang.String)) methods. With the second you can use an expression like `"${dateTime().minusWeeks(3)}"` which will calculate the date for you.

Comment: Great! I had searched for "duration" and "created Before" overlooked. Thank you.